# facebook php-sdk not logging out

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having a hard time getting this to work. I use the following to generate the logout url:

```
$logout = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=" . urlencode('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "&access_token=" . $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Which generates the correct (worked with the last version) url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2F...&access_token=AA....ZD
```

However this does not actually log the user out. I tried using

```
$facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'myurl'))
```

which generates pretty much the same url. This also did not work. I am lost as to why its not logging the user out. I actually tried manually putting the address into the address bar but it redirects me to the Facebook homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you request the **offline_access** permission when using the Facebook PHP SDK (and sometimes even without it), it makes the default logout functionality not work very well.  To fix this, following worked for me:

```
//change your logout url to 
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array( 'next' => ($fbconfig['baseurl'].'logout.php') ));

//on logout page
setcookie('fbs_'.$facebook->getAppId(), '', time()-100, '/', 'domain.com');
session_destroy();
header('Location: /');
```

Comment: thanks sudhir the setcookie on logout page worked just awesome. This is the only fix that worked for me for the facebook logout url.

Answer (score 3):

The facebook php sdk uses php sessions to tokens that keep you logged in. To clear it, you can just destroy the session.

index.php:

```
<a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
```

logout.php

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => FB_APP_ID, 'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET, 'cookie' => true));
$facebook->destroySession();
header('location: index.php');
```

FB_APP_ID and FB_SECRET are my specific apps info. Replace with your own.